# Graphing a line from two coordinates

Tags: graphs, line

Very new LaTeX user here!

There are a ton of impressive graphs on this site. I, however, am trying to make a nice looking line on a simple graph by plotting two (x,y) coordinates: (8, 2) and (-2, -3).

Can somebody please help me with this? Here's what I had in mind: http://www.algebrahelp.com/worksheets/cache/graph_10027_a.png

I've found a lot of information on parabolic graphs and much more advanced stuff, but nothing on really simple graphs.

Here's what I made:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thin, gray, ->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) 
    node [above, black] {$y$};  
    \draw [thin, gray, ->] (-10,0) -- (10,0)   
    node [right, black] {$x$};              
    \draw [draw=red,ultra thick] (8,2) -- (-2,-3);  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I spent a long time trying to figure this out and mad a pretty stupid looking graph (which is huge):

[image: My stupid graph]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `pgfplots` instead of directly using `tikz`:

[image]

### Notes

- The reason for suggesting the use of `pgfplots` (instead of `tikz`) is that `tikz` is designed for drawing and pgfplots (which uses `tikz`) is designed specifically for graphing. So, if what you are doing is graphing, you should use the tool that was designed for that. Sure, you can use `tikz` (especially for the image given in the question), but then when you want to add tick marks, a grid, perhaps a legend in the case of multiple equations on one graph, you end up doing a lot of the work that `pgfplots` has already done for you.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}
    \addplot [mark=none,  red,   ultra thick] coordinates { (8,2) (-2,-3)};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you recommend so?

Comment: @PeterGrill: I am sure, I am not the only one, being curious about your recommendation.  Hence my question/comment.  Maybe you should add this valuable information into your answer?  Merry christmay to you.

Comment: @Jan: Answer updated to include the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

For comparison of drawing with pure `tikz` and `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
with pure TikZ:

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
% grid
\draw [densely dashed, gray!50]    (-6,-6) grid (6,6);  
% ticks
\foreach \i in {-5,...,-1,1,2,...,5}
{
\draw (\i,0.1) -- ++ (0,-0.2) node[below,font=\scriptsize] {$\i$};
\draw (0.1,\i) -- ++ (-0.2,0) node[left, font=\scriptsize] {$\i$};
}
% axis
\draw [->] ( 0,-6) -- (0,6) node [left ] {$y$};
\draw [->] (-6, 0) -- (6,0) node [below] {$x$};
% graph
\draw [draw=red,thick] (-2,-6) -- (2,6);
\fill[red] (-1,-3) circle (1.5mm) (1,3) circle (1.5mm);
\draw [draw=blue]   (-6,-5) -- (6,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

with pgfplots:

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \begin{axis}[
%width=6cm,
axis lines=middle,
grid,
grid style={densely dashed},
xlabel=\(x\), ylabel=\(y\),
every axis plot/.style={very thick},
                ]
    \addplot coordinates { (8,2) (-2,-3)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]